# Must you enable translation of minor versions for Translation Review workflow?

Tags: translation-manager, sites-9.1

Translation Review lets Tridion Sites users send and receive translation jobs without closing the job in the configured translation management system (WorldServer or TMS).

The CMS user can review, reject, or even edit the translation segments during the configured workflow, which will then be sent back to translation.

I think the configuration to translate minor versions is *not required* for Translation Review, but I wanted to confirm.

*Must* you enable the [translation of minor versions](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/689673/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/enabling-translation-of-minor-versions-of-multimedia-components--components-and-pages) to make Translation Review work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Minor version translation deals with **source** item being in workflow.
Review functionality works with workflow on **target** item.

All you need for Review functionality is workflow on target items, that supports Translation Manager Review. And appropriate workflow steps on TMS or WS.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. And thanks for the clarification on the source and target context. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When I've set Translation Review up in the past the **AllowTranslateDynamicContent** setting was *not enabled* (so left commented out in the TranslationManager.xml file as per default) and Translation Review worked as expected.

```
<!-- Enable translation of minor versions. -->
<!-- <AllowTranslateDynamicContent>true</AllowTranslateDynamicContent> -->
```

So my take from that is the setting isn't directly part of Translation Review functionality as presumably the default is **false**.

I guess if enabled, this allows you send a minor/checked-in version for translation - which itself could then trigger Translation Review.

Comment: Awesome, I might have more questions. ;-)

Comment: I assume also if you had a minor version under an active standard or bundle workflow at the source publication you could also send it for translation and initiate a Translation Review workflow as that workflow would be running in the target publication? :s